# jQuery UI - Draggable is not a function?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I've trying to use the draggable effect on some divs on a page, but whenever I load the page, I get the error message:

```
Error: $(".draggable").draggable is not a function
```

I've had a look around it seemed other people were having this problem as they had not included the jQuery UI javascript file, but I definitely have.

The following is within the head tag of my page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Quick edit, I also have the jquery tools js included in the head of the page, if I remove this it works OK.  Has anyone managed to get these two working together?

Comment: Do you have a live link to the page with this problem?

Comment: No, it's just on my local machine atm

Answer (score 68):

A common reason this occurs is if you don't also load jqueryui after loading jquery.

For example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*EDIT.*
Replace the version number for each library with appropriate or latest values for [jquery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) and [jqueryui](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui).

If this doesn't solve the issue, review suggestions in the many other answers.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thx!  On a sidenote the updated library is now at:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 39):

4 years after the question got posted, but maybe it will help others who run into this problem. The answer has been posted elsewhere on StackExchange as well, but I lost the link and it's hard to find.

ANSWER: In jQueryTOOLS, the jQuery 'core' is also embedded if you use the default download.

When you load jQuery and jQuery tools, jQuery core gets defined twice and will 'unset' any plugins. 'Draggable' (from jQuery-UI) is such a plug-in.

The solution is to use jQuery tools WITHOUT the jQuery 'core' files and everything will work fine.

Comment: +1 While this wasn't the exact solution to my problem, it lead me to the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: And in 2017 this help me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I have no clue what you mean with this answer. I've loaded jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js in this specific order. I dont know what jqueryTOOLS is nor do I use it.

Comment: Refer to the part in the question below "quick edit".

Comment: An .aspx page of mine loaded jquery, then jquery-ui and the jquery once more. I removed the line that was responsible for the latter loading of jquery and problem was fixed. +1!

Answer (score 27):

1. Install [jquery-ui-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui-dist)

   use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)

   `npm install --save jquery-ui-dist`

   or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)

   `yarn add jquery-ui-dist`
2. Import it inside your app code

   `import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';`

   or

   `require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui');`

Comment: great ans.saved my time

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: Saved my time while using this with React

Comment: Upvoted (it works and it's great that the answer includes the alternates npm/yarn import/require!), but the answer could use some explanation on why this works with `jquery-ui-dist` but not with `jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your code follows this order-

```js
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: the script in OP would suggest it does.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the jQuery object and *NOT* the element itself.  If you select by class, you may not be getting what you expect.

Open up a console and look at what your selector code returns.  In Firebug, you should see something like:

```
jQuery( div.draggable )
```

You may have to go into an array and grab the first element: `$('.draggable').first()` Then call draggable() on that jQuery object and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

You can import these js Files. It worked fine for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue can also be caused if you include the normal jquery library twice. I had the following line twice, in my body and head.

It never caused any problems until I tried to use jquery UI as well.

Answer (score 2):

I went through both your question and a another [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219513/uncaught-typeerror-draggable-is-not-a-function).
In the end, the following answer helped me sorting things out:
[uncaught-typeerror-draggable-is-not-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219513/uncaught-typeerror-draggable-is-not-a-function/40155874#40155874)

To get rid of :

> $(".draggable").draggable is not a function anymore

I had to **put links to Javascript libraries above the script tag** I expected to be working.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#container-speed").draggable();
    });
</script>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="rowbackground"style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
                <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
                <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, this works for me (I couldn't get this working with the **Google API** links you were using):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Beef Burrito</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="draggable" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">asdasd</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work (you can check in firebug jQuery.ui is undefined):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Try use follow code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Why loading jQuery twice?

Comment: I don`t remember. Perhaps I was not paying attention

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for some one :

In my case i was able to remove this error by first loading the js files on which draggable depends. They were ui.mouse.js, ui.core and ui.widget
i.e
    UI Core
    Widget Factory
    Mouse Interaction

Make sure the script tag for loading dependencies lies above the draggable js loading tag.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Tools and jQuery UI get in conflict because they both declare `jQuery.tabs` and the conflict prevents the second one (in this case jQuery UI) from being loaded. This is the reason why you get a `draggable is not a function` error.

A solution to this problem is to create a custom version of jQuery Tools (from [here](http://jquerytools.org/download/)) without the tabs functionality.

Informations about the conflict found here: [Can JQuery UI and JQuery tools work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374720/can-jquery-ui-and-jquery-tools-work-together#1721944)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Use

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause to this error is usually because you're probably using a bootstrap framework and have already included a jquery file somewhere else may at the head or right above the closing body tag, in that case all you need to do is to include the jquery ui file wherever you have the jquery file or on both both places and you'll be fine...

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

just include the above jquery ui script wherever you are importing the jquery file along with other bootstrap dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an Ionic app be sure to include jquery and jquery-ui before ionic.bundle.js!

such a waste of time for something so trivial  :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this junk at the bottom of my _layout mvc page that I found via chromes debugger (network section) loading jquery 1.10.2 after the jquery / jqueryui sections at the top of the same file. When I removed all that .sortable and .draggable started working.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason for this error was that i loaded the jquery plugin defining the function, in the wrong place. It needs to be after jquery and jquery ui, after the content, but before the function call.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for another reason and my eye needed one hour to find out.
I had copy-pasted the script tags that load jquery :

```
<script src="**https**://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="**http**://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My website was using https when accessed from a mobile browser and refused to load jquery-ui without https.