# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, typeerror

hello everyone i am trying to make some divs draggable and i have managed to do that with jquery-ui. i also have a script that removes 2 divs and combine them in a single one (like if they have been merged together) but when i call the draggable function on the new "merged" div i get the error is the title... so what is the problem ? how is it possible that .draggable function work one place and not in an other (on the same file)!!

this is the draggable function:

```
function drag($class){
$("."+$class).draggable({
containment: ".tab-content",
grid: [ 3, 3 ],
zIndex:100,
obstacle: "#nothere",
preventCollision: true,
drag:
function(){
    $(".test").css("background-color","red");
    $(this).css("background-color","green");
    }

});
}
```

first i called it for the test class which work perfectly with no error

```
drag("test");
```

but when i call it another time inside the merge function it return the error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

```
drag("test:not(.ui-draggable)");
```

the js file are loaded properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: May be you didn't load jQuery UI files

Comment: have you included jQueryUI?

Comment: is this question so hard that no one can solve it  !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but since I had the same problem and couldn't find the answer...

I had all of the correct scripts included, checked that the links were valid etc and it still wasn't working.

I then moved the script references to be directly above the code that calls .draggable and.. it works perfectly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $(".regionStyle li").draggable();
                $(".regionStyle").droppable({
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this)
                        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                        .find("p")
                        .html("Item Dropped!");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to include in your project this files:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Check their [example](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). Use Developer tools (F12 under Chrome) to see if all resources have been imported.