# Twitter Boostrap Modal window -draggable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have  the links below that open modal windows, I want to make the modal window draggable. For some reason my modal window draggable script is not working.

here is modal window code  and javascript and fiddle link below

[MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s2f0jrzc/8/)

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade video2 advSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Video 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="responsive-embed-16by9-iframe-youtube">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

              <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" type="video/mp4"> </video>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(".advSearchModal").draggable({
      handle: ".modal-header"
  });
```

Comment: You can view this thread, it has been answered :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22509959/6296341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not include jQuery UI in your code.  This is required to be included as it is not a standard part of jQuery.