# Draggable is not a function

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack

I tried

```
npm i -g jquery-ui
```

then I did

```
import 'jquery-ui'
```

and when I execute this function :

```
$(".drop_zone").draggable({ cursor: "pointer" });
```

it tells me this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default(...)(...).draggable is not a function

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895894/jquery-ui-draggable-is-not-a-function

Comment: Yes, thanks! I had to Install jquery-ui-dist.