# In angular 8, drag and drop with custom clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, drag-and-drop

Drag the content from the one component list and drop the content into another component and content will not be dropped into particular position.
Drag the div any drop any certain position on the page. I have found solution in **jquery 1.9.1**

```
<div class="dragger">Drag</div>
<div class="dragger">Drag</div>
<div class="dragger">Drag</div>
<div class="dragger">Drag</div>
<div class="dragger">Drag</div>
<div class="dropper">
    <p>Drop</p>
</div>
```

**jquery 1.9.1+javascript**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dragger').draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: function () {
                //Code here
                return $("<div class='dragger'></div>").append("Hi");
            }
        });


        $(".dropper").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {

                $(this)
                    .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                    .find("p")
                    .html("Dropped!");

                var element = $('.ui-draggable-dragging');
                var currentDrop=$(this);
                return element.clone().appendTo(currentDrop);
            }
        });
    });
```

but when I will implement that code in latest jquery version then it will show ERROR **TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function**

how to implement that code in angular 8

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post and **don't just include a link to Fiddle**. Links rot, and your post should stand alone from any other resource; this question will lose any value to future visitors if jsFiddle is blocked or goes away in the future!

Comment: In addition to what @Shree pointed out, having your code in a link instead of in the post potentially makes it more difficult for people to find your post in Google, which diminishes the usefulness of the post to future readers since fewer people will be able to read and potentially benefit from it.

Comment: I have edited my question so don't put my question on HOLD. please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28207155/965146

Comment: Thanks, but not worked for me if any drag and drop package do you know that works like a https://www.wix.com/  website