# jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function in php

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

i am getting jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function error in draggable.The scripts loaded are as follows.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(function () {
        
        $("#dragdiv .drag_pet").draggable(
                {
                    //helper:"clone",
                    containment: "document",
                    revert: true,
                    revertDuration: 200
                });
});
```

how to solve this?

Comment: add `https://` not `http` in your script src - but thats not the only problem i believe.

Comment: 2 of 4 of your scripts are 404.. so that probably doesn't help

Comment: ....and as per @freedomn-m your last `two scripts src` does not exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895894/jquery-ui-draggable-is-not-a-function

Comment: 2 of 4 of your scripts are 404.how to solve this