# jQuery UI Tabs + jQuery Tools Tabs (Flowplayer) conflict

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tools

I have exactly the same problem as the person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599916/jquery-tools-tabs-conflicts-with-jquery-ui).
I know how to solve it. You're supposed to change the following in the jQuery Tools.js, right?

find:

```
$.fn.tabs = function(query, conf) {
```

change to something like this:

```
$.fn.fpTabs = function(query, conf) {
```

My problem is that I just can't find that line anywhere, not even with the search function of my editor!! 
I've downloaded the newest version of Flowplayer.org's jQuery Tools and I uploaded it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ispnQMVH
Can you help me figure out how to do this?

If there's a nother way to prevent jQuery-ui tabs to inferfere with jQuery Tools tabs, then please let me know :)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You might want to patch the non-minified version and then minify your patched version.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comment. I'm not quite sure if I understand what I'm supposed to do exactly. Could you explain it for dummies, please? :)

Comment: You're looking at the minimized version where everything is packed together and some variables will have been renamed. Trying to find the specific `.tabs` you're looking for in that mess will be difficult. You'll have better luck if you start with the human readable version of the plugin.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Where would I find a human readable version of the plugin? http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html

Comment: I left some notes in answer, need a bit more space than a comment provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting this down as an answer because it would be a mess in a comment.

Looks like you can grab the unminified source from Github:

> https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools

You could also try a quick hack to rename the tabs plugin in situ. If you load the jQuery Tools Tabs JavaScript file, then load a little patcher like this:

```
(function($) {
    // Rename the tabs in-place.
    $.fn.fpTabs = $.fn.tabs;
    delete $.fn.tabs;
})(jQuery);
```

and then load jQuery-UI:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/jquery.tools.tabs-renamer.js"></script> <!-- see above -->
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You'll have to change the names of course but it should work if you load things in the above order.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now, I only have to figure out how to do this in Wordpress where I don't use direct script calls, but wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script. The tough thing will only be to tell Wordpress which script to load first, I guess.