# How to include both of `jquery.tools.js` and `jquery.tokeninput.js`

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools, jquery-tokeninput

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can JQuery UI and JQuery tools work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374720/can-jquery-ui-and-jquery-tools-work-together)

I have a page which requires JQuery's tokeninput (for drop-downs) and also JQuery's "tools" (for tooltips etc.)

If I do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
```

Then Chrome gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} 
has no method 'type'    (jquery.tokeninput.js:139)
```

If I put the JS calls the other way around, then everything loads, but the `tokeninput` method is not available on the textfields.

If I have just the `jquery.tokeninput.js` file then the `tokeninput` works well, everything is OK, apart from the features introduced in `jquery.tools.js` aren't available, such as `tooltip`.

FYI: My entire list of scripts that I include are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.10-redmond/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fileinput.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the answer appears to be here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721944/220627